# App or web-app to decode encoded strings (better than CyberChef's "magic")

Tags: text-processing, translation, english, ascii, encoding

I often have strings that are encoded with unknown encoding methods that I need to decode.  Note that these strings are not *encrypted*; they are simply *encoded*.

I typically use [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) for these types of tasks, but it often falls short.  Often it fails with an error due to bugs in its logic, or simply does not take enough of the guess-work out of the process.  (If you are not familiar with CyberChef, its "magic" function is designed for this type of task, but in my experience, it only occasionally generates satisfactory results.)

Sometimes, to help with the task, I have a a short "crib" available (a sequence of characters that I know are present in the decoded string). Even with a crib, CyberChef just isn't cutting it (pun initially unintended, then intended).

Types of encoding (and I'll use that term loosely here) that need to be handled include ROT13, ROT47, uuencode, BASE64, ASCII, punycode, little-endian <-> big-endian transforms, 8 <-> 16 bit-depth conversions, hex <-> decimal <-> octal representations, UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, and UTF-32BE.

Typically, a string has been encoded with more than 1 of these algorithms.  As a simple example, BASE64 then ROT13.

The encoded strings are sometimes as short as 256 bytes, and are typically less than 2Kb.

The decoded strings will be in English (any variety of that language), but at times they may include mostly unique non-dictionary words.

The strings are not particularly private, so a web-app is fine.  If not, a Windows application (portable preferred, but not required) or Android app will work.

Gratis is preferred, but cost can be anything under 10 $/€ (no recurring costs, please).

Comment: I imagine you're not expecting this as an appropriate answer, but: have you considered python?  Most or all of those conversions are one-liners in python.  Yes, it's a programming language, but if you've never written a program don't let that put you off.

Comment: @CroadLangshan Thank you for your feedback. The trick is not so much the conversions/decodings, but trying all the possibilities in different orders and automagically determining which ones are most likely generating meaningful decoded strings.  In theory, that's largely what "magic" does in CyberChef, but unfortunately it currently has too many issues to be very useful.  Just as an example, a string might be BASE64 encoded, and then have ROT13 applied.  Hard to guess the encoding just by looking at the original string (and that's a simple example with only 2 transforms).

Comment: Even though this is simple encodings, I bet the people on https://crypto.stackexchange.com would know what algorithms this software should use.  If you knew that, it might be easier to find software for this?

Comment: @CroadLangshan Hmmm... that's a real interesting idea.  Do you think there are real algorithms that could be applicable, or just brute force until something resolves that looks like English (ASCII 0x20-0x7E, with at least x% of characters being A-Za-z)?

Comment: @SteveBarnes While we are talking about this, did you already finish coding it in Python? ;)

Comment: ROT13 is not an encoding (as you might have noticed as well, by your "loosely"), it's an encryption method, since it doesn't change the character set. An encoding method only deals with a change in character set (e.g., BASE64 doesn't include many problematic punctuation in the output). It is very different from other encodings in your list, I think, and handling them will require different techniques than handling pure encodings (which is what the rest of encodings in your list are)

Comment: @justhalf Thanks. Yes I agree, ROT13 (and ROT47) are traditionally considered ciphers, largely because they were originally used for that purpose.  Since they are pure substitution ciphers, they require no password or key.  Thus, they wind up having the same effect and complexity (and security) as encodings, which simply always convert one set of bits to another, without any variability.

Comment: I know little about crypto and do not know the answer, but my guess is that yes, there are algorithms that might help